# Python code - return first word in a string with vowel

Tags: python

Very new to Python.I would like to return the first work from an input string that starts with a vowel. If found return the word, else return an empty string. Have the below code however the else statement doesn't seems to work.

```
for word in string_list:
    if word[0] in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
        return word
    else:
        return ""
```

Comment: Have you actually defined a function (using `def`) anywhere?

Comment: Could you show your whole code? Your logic is correct but the placement of the `return` indicates you want this to be a function. You should also want to store your results into a `list`

Comment: I have defined the function as def first_starting_vowel(string_list):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the for loop will execute only once if you are using it inside the function because you are just checking the first word and returning from the function. Instead, you can use only `if` condition inside the for loop and returning empty string part outside the for loop.

And you also need to check with small and capital letters/vowels. string_list here is the list of strings.

```
def findFirstWordWithVowel(string_list):
    for word in string_list:
        if word[0] in "aeiouAEIOU":
            return word
    return ""
```

Comment: thanks, in this particular case I been asked to check only the lower case. Thank you all

Answer (score 4):

You only `return` inside a function, for example:

```
string_list = ['frst', 'hello', 'and']


def first_with_vowel(words):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    for word in words:
        if any(vowel == word[0] for vowel in vowels):
            return word
    return ""


print(first_with_vowel(string_list))
```

**Output**

```
and
```

To verify if any of the vowels is the first letter of a word you could use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). The function any evals to `True` if any of vowels is the first letter of the word.

Also in your code the `else` is misplaced, if the first word does not start with a vowel you will return `""`, even if the second does. You can remove the else, and return `""` when the loop is over (like in the example code above), meaning there was no word that started with a vowel.

Comment: Seems to be a better answer

Answer (score 0):

return should be used in a function. so,

```
def checker(word):
    if word[0] in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
         return word
    else:
         return ""

checker("isuru")
```

this works.

Comment: What is the purpose of string_list in your function? If it is a list (which is not defined in your function), you are only executing the for loop once.

Comment: def first_starting_vowel(string_list):